# How to remove rows from a dataframe that are identical to another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames `df1` and `df2`.
For my analysis, I need to remove rows from `df1` that have identical column values (`Email`) in `df2`?

```
>>df1
   First  Last  Email
0 Adam   Smith  email@email.com
1 John   Brown  email2@email.com
2 Joe    Max    email3@email.com
3 Will   Bill   email4@email.com


>>df2
  First  Last   Email
0 Adam   Smith  email@email.com
1 John   Brown  email2@email.com
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try this:

```
cond = df1['Email'].isin(df2['Email'])
df1.drop(df1[cond].index, inplace = True)

>>df1
    First   Last    Email
2   Joe     Max     email3@email.com
3   Will    Bill    email4@email.com
```

Comment: This method does not work if you don't have a unique column (email in this case). In this case you can join two or more columns into one with `df1[['First', 'Last']].agg('-'.join, axis=1)` if they are strings.

Answer (score 9):

Simpler to use `isin()` with `dropna()`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

```
df1[~df1.isin(df2)].dropna()
```

Comment: Quick question, what does the tilde stands for?

Comment: It's a negation. Will turn all True to False and vice versa.

Comment: This is wrong. It compares the values one at a time, a row can have mixed cases. Even when a row has all true, that doesn't mean that same row exists in the other dataframe, it means the values of this row exist in the columns of the other dataframe but in multiple rows.